Minimum number of searches to find matching element in two list.
I have two list, say list1 and list2, containing integers and both having size $N$. We have a fixed overlap ratio in range $(0, 1)$. If overlap ratio is $0.3$ and $N = 10$ it means both list have around $3$ integers in common. However this doesn’t guarantee that the indices for these elements will be same. In most of the cases they will be different.
Here is how search is performed: You pick a random index, $i$, in range $(0, N)$ and create two sub lists: sublist1 and sublist2.
Step 1: Send list1[i] element to sublist1
Step 2: Send list2[i] element to sublist2
Step 3: Check if sublist1 and sublist2 have common elements irrespective of their indices in sublist
Step 4: If no common element is found increase $i$ with $1$ and repeat. If $i = N +1$ set $i = 1$ again.
I wrote a python program with overlap ration $0.3$ and here are the results
N          Avg Trials    % of N        √N          Ratio (Trials/√N)
120        17           14.17%         11          1.55
12,000     177          1.47%          110         1.61
100,000    539          0.539%         316         1.70
1,000,000  1,584        0.1584%        1,000       1.58
10,000,000 4,975        0.04975%       3,162       1.57

$N$ denotes the length of list. Then I ran the code multiple times and after running it multiple times I calculated the average trials needed that is in Avg Trials. % of N indicates the percentage of range needed to search (average).
I am not good at probability. This suggests that it might be following the birthday bound. If someone could help me with more details and help generalise these results. I seek help for following:

Given $N$ and overlap ratio what will be the minimum number of trials that ensure there is atleast one element in sublist.
If this matching follows a birthday bound, if yes, then why?

The final goal: Minimum number of trials required to find an element of list2 that is also present in list1. And in both sublist.
Example:
List1 = $[52579, 46780, 36228, 40369, 26694, 36744, 9651, 98806, 5305, 64566]$
List2 = $[46780, 56910, 80182, 63250, 53981, 5305, 76771, 9651, 61251, 76094]$
Let $i = 2$
Trial 1
sublist1 = $[46780]$
sublist2 = $[56910]$
Since there is no matching element we include next elements
Thus $i = 2+1 = 3$.
sublist1 = $[46780, 36228]$
sublist2 = $[56910, 80182]$
Again there is no matching element so we keep including more additional element.
Trial 7 the picture looks like
sublist1 = $[46780, 36228, 40369, 26694, 36744, 9651, 98806]$
sublist2 = $[56910, 80182, 63250, 53981, 5305, 76771, 9651]$
Here we have $9651$ in sublist2 which occur in sublist1. Hence here trials are $7$.

I don't get how with a ratio of $0.3$ and $N=3$, we arrive to 3 common elements.

It's not clear which is your final goal. You want to know how many searches do you have to make to find the first element in list2 that is contained also in list1? Or is something else?

@nicola sorry my mistake corrected

The ratio looks like it goes to $\pi/2$.

@martycohen I didn't get it. What is meant by $\pi/2$?

The ratio table - $1.57 \approx \pi/2$.

Given two lists $A,B$ each with size $N$ and overlap ratio $\alpha \in (0,1)$ i.e.,
$$\#A \cap B = \alpha N,$$
consider the random sequence of elements $X_i,i=1,2,\ldots$ and $Y_j,j=1,2,\ldots$ which are drawn to form two lists $L_A$ and $L_B$ so
that the lists are sequentially $$\{X_1\},\{X_1,X_2\},\ldots,\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_t\}$$ and $$\{Y_1\},\{Y_1,Y_2\},\ldots,\{Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_t\}.$$
Let the lists at stage $t$ be denoted
$$L_A(t)=\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_t\}$$ and $$L_B(t)=\{Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_t\}.$$
It is straightforward to give an average case analysis which will hold in a typical attack with high probability given the huge size of the list that you are considering. It is similar to the birthday paradox analysis which you can find on Wikipedia:
In the sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ each element $X_i$ is in the intersection with probability $\alpha.$ Similarly in the sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ each element $Y_i$ is in the intersection with probability $\alpha.$
So, at time $t,$ (after $t$ samples from each of the lists) there are on average $M_t=\alpha t$ samples (we may need to take the integer part but ignore for now) which are from each of $A$ and $B$. Denote these sets $I_A(t)$ and $I_B(t)$ and they are subsets of $L_A(t)$ and $L_B(t)$ respectively.
Now, we need to calculate the probability that $L_A(t)$ and $L_B(t)$ have no overlap. We use independence of samples throughout. For a fixed element in $L_A(t)$ the probability that it is not present in $L_B(t)$ is
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha N}\right)^{M_t}
$$
since we are targeting a single element of $\alpha N$ elements in the intersection and doing this via $M_t$ independent trials.
This is now repeated $M_t$ times for each element in $L_A(t)$, i.e., $M_t$ times.
So the probability that there is no overlap up to and including stage $t$ is
$$
P_{fail}(t)=\left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha N}\right)^{M_t^2}=
\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha N}\right)^{\alpha N} \right]^{M_t^2/\alpha N}
\sim \exp\left(-M_t^2/\alpha N\right).
$$
Recall that $M_t = \alpha t,$ so $P_{fail}(t)\sim \exp\left(-\alpha t^2/N\right).$ To make this probability of fail $1/e\approx 37\%$ we choose
$t=\sqrt{N/\alpha}.$
By the way for your numbers (I don't think memory of $10^{80}$ is realistic by the way) this gives $t=\sqrt{10N/3}=\sqrt{10^{81}/3}\approx 1.83 \times 10^{40}.$
This is not a practical attack with given parameters. A zetabyte (EB) is $10^{21}$ bytes and is so large that all the data in the world is just a few zetabytes, see here. In comparison we have $10^{80}$ sized lists here.


Given N and overlap ratio what will be the minimum number of trials that ensure there is [at least] one element in sublist.

The worst case scenario is where the overlaps are all at the end, so you need (1-overlap)*N+1 elements to guarantee a common element.

If this matching follows a birthday bound, if yes, then why?

The birthday bound is how many you need for a 50% chance of success. If you want 100% chance of success, you need 366 (or 367 taking into account leap years) people. If you want to know what the minimum you need to have a 50% chance of a common element, that's a different question.

If i=N+1 set i=1 again.

I'm confused as to how you get to i=N+1. If you've gone through all of the elements, then you're guaranteed to get overlap.
